# Eliminating a potential racing condition

Tags: c, pipe, fork, bandwidth

I am supposed to measure the latency and bandwidth between two processes. To do this, I wrote a simple program in C using pipe and fork. To see that everything works, I wanted the parent process and the child process to work alternately. So I wanted the parent process to stop after writing and continue after the child process read and printed the string with 'a'.

I used kill() and pause() along with sleep. My problem is that from time to time the program terminates itself and in other cases it works fine because it may not hit the race condition, I suppose.

Up to now I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define DATASIZE 5

int count = 0;

double diff = 0;

void wakeup_handler(int sig)
{
    // Do nothing
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int i, n;

    double total_time = 0;
    struct timeval t1, t2;

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Child Process
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        
        close(pipefd[0]);

        char tmp1[DATASIZE];

        // Set tmp to 'a'

        for (i = 0; i < DATASIZE; i++)
        {
            tmp1[i] = 'a';
        }

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

        signal(SIGUSR1, wakeup_handler);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            write(pipefd[1], tmp1, sizeof(tmp1));
            pause();
            count++;
            printf("CountC: %d\n", count);
        }

        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
        diff = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec);          // sec to ms
        diff += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1e6; // us to sec
        
        //Correction of 10 seconds because of the 10 seconds sleep in the parent process
        
        // diff+= diff - 10;

        double band = (DATASIZE * 1000) / diff;
        printf("Average latency: %lf seconds\n", diff / 1000);
        printf("Average bandwidth: %lf Mbps\n", band / 1e6);
        close(pipefd[1]);

    }
    // Parent Process
    else
    {
        close(pipefd[1]);

        char tmp2[DATASIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            // printf("Parent: Iteration %d...\n", i+1);
            read(pipefd[0], tmp2, sizeof(tmp2));
            printf("%s\n", tmp2);
            sleep(0.01);
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        }

        close(pipefd[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need the null character at the end of `tmp2` for `printf` to work properly

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ed. I now initialize tmp2 to the size of DATASIZE + 1 and set tmp2[DATASIZE] = '\0' but the process still terminates before the end.

Comment: Aside: the argument type for `sleep` is `unsigned int`. With `sleep(0.01)`, the `double` value of `0.01` will be *truncated* to an integer value of `0`. If you want sub-second precision sleeps, use [`nanosleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).

Comment: Before after `close(pipefd[0]);` in the parent process add `wait` - see manual page [wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, with your adaptions it ran through all my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the race condition where a signal may be delivered *before* `pause` has executed, instead of *"buying more time"* by calling `sleep` in the parent process, `sigprocmask` may be used to *block* the delivery of signals in the child process, delaying their arrival until they are later *unblocked*. A delayed signal is said to be *pending*.

`sigsuspend` can be used to temporarily *unblock* signals (by changing the signal mask) while it waits for a signal to arrive.

To avoid the race condition where the parent process sends the data-request signal *before* the child process has finished establishing its signal handling, the pipe can be used to transmit some initial data. By executing a blocking `read` in the parent process, the child process can indicate it is ready with an initial `write` that unblocks the parent.

When the work is complete, the parent process should `wait` for the child process to terminate.

For significantly improved portability, prefer `sigaction` to `signal`.

Here is a cursory refactoring of your example. However, for the sake of brevity, it has no error handling.

Do note the blocking nature of `write` and `read` help create a *lockstep* here, ensuring the parity of iterations between processes. Otherwise, calling `kill` *N* times does not guarantee *N* writes to the pipe, as a *to-be-delivered* signal would be dropped if it is already *pending*. An important part of what makes this synchronization work is that the parent process immediately waits for the data it requests.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct packet {
    char buffer[32];
};

void wakeup_handler(int sig)
{
    /* Do nothing */
    (void) sig;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* each process receives a copy of the number of tests to run */
    unsigned cycles = 1000;
    int pipefd[2];

    pipe(pipefd);
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* Child process */
        close(pipefd[0]);

        struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = wakeup_handler };
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

        sigset_t mask, original;

        sigemptyset(&mask);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
        /* block (delay) delivery of the SIGUSR1 signal */
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &original);

        /* write some initial data
         * letting the parent know the child has finished
         * setting up its signal handling
         */
        int ready = 1;
        write(pipefd[1], &ready, sizeof ready);

        struct timeval t1, t2;
        int count = 0;
        double diff = 0;

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

        while (cycles--) {
            struct packet output = { "aaaaa" };

            /* temporary restore the original signal mask
             * and wait for a signal to arrive
             * (including previously delayed signals)
             */
            sigsuspend(&original);

            write(pipefd[1], &output, sizeof output);
            printf("CountC: %d\n", ++count);
        }

        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

        diff = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec);          // sec to ms
        diff += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1e6; // us to sec
        double band = (sizeof (struct packet) * 1000) / diff;
        printf("Average latency: %lf seconds\n", diff / 1000);
        printf("Average bandwidth: %lf Mbps\n", band / 1e6);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        /* ensure child does not run off */
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Parent process */
    close(pipefd[1]);

    /* block execution in the parent process until
     * some initial data arrives indicating the child process
     * is ready to receive signals
     */
    int initialized;
    read(pipefd[0], &initialized, sizeof initialized);

    while (cycles--) {
        struct packet input;

        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        read(pipefd[0], &input, sizeof input);
        printf("%.*s\n", (int) sizeof input.buffer, input.buffer);
    }

    close(pipefd[0]);

    /* wait for the child process to terminate */
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. In case of a further question I would like to contact you again but up to now I think, I have understood what you wrote.

Comment: I'm going to accept. But I were not sure whether you still see my comments then.

Comment: Thank you again. It hink I understood what you did.